# Simple question about LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, database-connection

I can't understand one thing. Suppose I already have these coded entities:

```
[Table(Name = "Rates")]
public class Rate
{
    private EntityRef<Product> _Product;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public String RateID 
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String ProductID 
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public Double VolumeInTons 
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public Decimal Volume 
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public Decimal Cost 
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public UInt32 Year 
    { get; set; }

    [Association(Storage = "_Product", OtherKey = "ProductID")]
    public Product Product
    {
        get { return this._Product.Entity; }
        set { this._Product.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

And

```
[Table(Name="Products")]
public class Product
{
    private EntitySet<Rate> _Rates;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey= true)]
    public String ProductID
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String Name
    { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public String Category
    { get; set; }

    [Association(Storage="_Rates", OtherKey="ProductID")]
    public EntitySet<Rate> Rates
    {
        get { return this._Rates; }
        set { this._Rates.Assign(value); }
    }
}
```

- Should I have a physical database to connect to with the same table definitions (to use datacontext in my application)?
- Suppose I have created a database. Should it contain the same table definitions or does `LINQ to SQL` create them?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx) method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have a database, you connect to it from Visual Studio and drag-and-drop the tables into the design mode of your `DataContext`. Visual Studio will then generate the corresponding classes for you.

Alternatively, and probably the answer you are after, is that you already have the generated classes (for example: from a different system with the database), and you want to create the database according to your class definitions. You should then, somewhere early in your code, call once [DataContext.CreateDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx) (as also noted by Reniuz), and the database will be created. Note that on your next run, you don't need to create the database again.

Comment: Ok. I've seen the routine to achieve this. So I should inherit from `DataContext` and just use composition of all my tables inside it?